# System.Net.Mail reference does not exist

Tags: c#, winforms, system.net.mail, system.net

I have a problem creating application to send email.

I already have one working as a Windows Forms Application and then decided to do the same from the empty project, because I need to make a background application now.

I used the `System.Net.Mail` namespace for that in a Windows Forms. Then added the same code to the new project.

However, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Net'.

The 'System.Net' reference is included in the project references list and I can't find anything named 'System.Net.Mail' in the list of possible references. The point is that I didn't have those errors in Windows Forms app.

Comment: What version of .NET and Visual Studio are you using? `System.Net.Mail` was introduced in 2005/2.0, but in .NET 1.1/2003 it was called `System.Web.Mail`.

Comment: The `System.Net.Mail` classes are contained in the "System.dll" file. Make sure you have a reference to `System` listed under References in your project.

Comment: Yeah. All you say I know. I use the latest Visual Studio. Express Edition for Desktop. And I definitely add the reference of System.Net.Mail to the project references list. I will post the simplest code below. Try to create empty project and paste it.

Comment: It's not working out to past code in nice form, so just try to add "using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;" to the empty project and add System.Net to references list.

Comment: Use a project template to keep out of trouble until you learn more about .NET

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this in Visual Studio 2012, but even when I set the compiler to use `.NET 2.0` I still did not encounter this issue.

It is possible that you are missing the reference for `System.dll` which includes the namespace `System.Net.Mail`. Just as an precaution as you didn't include any sample code I will include a simple implementation of a Mail client as an example.

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-server.MyDomain.com"))
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;

        mail.From = new MailAddress("MyEmail@MyDomain.com");
        mail.To.Add("ToThisEmail@MyDomain.com");

        client.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Even though I wasn't able to reproduce this I would still recommend that you verify that you are compiling your project against the same target framework as your previous client.

You can do this by right-clicking on your project and selecting `Target framework` under the `Application` tab.

**Edit:** It might be worth taking a screenshot of your current references and uploading it here at stackoverflow. It would give us an better overview of potential issues or conflicts.

[image]

There should be no need to modify your `App.config`, but as a reference here you have mine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

**Edit2:**

**Add the `System.dll` reference.**

1. Right click on your project and choose `Add Reference`.
2. Find and add `System` (or `System.dll`) under `Assemblies` and `Framework`.
3. Click `OK` to save.

Comment: Maybe I should do something with app.config file in addition. I just added references with right click on the Reference on Solution Explorer and "Add Reference".

Comment: I tried to change framework from my "Framework 4.5" to 4.0, 3.0. It's still the same error.

Comment: Maybe try uploading a screenshot of your references. It could provide us with better insight.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make any modifications in the App.config, but I'll include mine for reference.

Comment: Screenshot: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B18cSIbjPPomdHFsdGNEdzZaYjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You are missing `System.dll`.

Comment: Hehe, no worries. I included instructions in my answer if needed.

Comment: Using VS 2013 and targetting .net 4.0 I am getting the same error.  The type of project is "C# Portable  library".  When I try to add reference ( manually browsing to the directory ) , I get pop-up error "This component is already referenced by the build system". What else I can attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Following changes solved my problem.
Change Target framework to .Net Framework 4 from .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.

Client Profile framework creates many such issues.