# I am not able to add System.Net.Mail reference. However it is present in Object Browser

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to add an attachment in mail through my app. However `System.Net.Mail` does not work for me. System.Net has only references for `System.Net.Browser`, `System.Net.Sockets`, and `System.Net.NetworkInformation`

Comment: Is your question similar or answered in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561320/system-net-mail-reference-does-not-exist

Comment: Nope. That didnt solve my prob and I am facing the same issue. I am not able to add System.dll. It gives me error that "The reference to the higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project"

Comment: There is no System.Net.Mail assembly for WP8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Net.Mail` isn't supported by Windows Phone. As far as I know, the only way to send a mail on Windows Phone without using a third-party library is the [`EmailComposeTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). But as you noticed, it does not support attachments.